# Nextjs How to map multiple routes to one page?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js, query-string

I have a page called **blog** in my `nextjs` version 9.

`Next` create a route **/blog** for my page. Now I want to have these routes to be mapped to the same blog page and consequently the blog component:

```
1. /blog/cat1/gold
2. /blog/cat2/silver
3. /blog/cat3/bronze
```

Actually, I want to use them as `query parameters` in the route but I don't want to follow this format:

```
1. /blog?cat=cat1&color=gold
2. /blog?cat=cat2&color=silver
3. /blog?cat=cat3&color=bronze
```

I used `next/router` `asPath` but it is completely **client-side** and by reloading it returns **404**!

In `nextjs 9` dynamic routing has provided which may help me but the thing is I want to have only one component and different routes.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't specify your web server, so I will give an example using expressjs.

```
const app = next({ dev })

app.prepare().then(() => {
   const server = express();
   server.get("/blog/:cat/:color", (req, res) => app.render(req, res, `/blog`));
})
```

If you need to access the value in the page, you can use `getInitialProps` to get the value by accessing `req.params.cat` and `req.params.color`.

Another way is by passing the value directly when calling `app.render` function:

```
app.render(req, res, '/posts', { cat: req.params.cat, color: req.params.color })
```

Here is the [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js).

Comment: My web server is express. Let me try this and then let you know . Thanks

Comment: How will the <Link> look like on the client side? I mean what will be the values of "href" and "as" ?
What if I have another route "/blog/cat1" which will get more priority?

Comment: In express web server, they will not serve "/blog/cat1" except you define another API for that. So there is no priority there, because the listener is totally a different function.

"/blog/:cat/:color" will only listen to any browser requests that have 3 parameters: blog, cat, and color. For href and as value, you can take a look from here https://github.com/zeit/next.js#with-link

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [Next's dynamic routers](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes). Just create a folder for blog-posts and add a dynamic page under it like this:

```
  /pages/blog/[...slug].tsx
```

Now on your `[...slug].tsx` will catch all paths, no matter in what depth. And you can catch the path params from the router's query -field. Try this with any path under `/blog/**/*` -path and it will list path elements:

```js
const Blog = () => {

  const { 
    query: { slug } 
  } = useRouter(); 

  return (
    <ul>
      {query.slug.map(value => <li key={value}>{value}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```